# strategy for drawing lots of lines and graphics on android mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am drawing up to 100+ icons and 100+ lines on a Mapview.  Would creating and overlay for each line/icon be suitable or should I use a single overlay?  What are the advantages to using a single or multiple overlays?

thanks

Comment: are these lements dynamic or static?